# Running Opencover and ReportGenerator in Docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, opencover, reportgenerator, powershell-v6.0

Im trying to run opencover and reportgenerator for an asp.net core application using this image microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0.0 , I have an opencover powershell script, and want to install powershell for linux inside the container to run that script, any guidance or solution for this ?

Comment: The commands and documentation for running this image are on dockerhub https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore-build/. Have you tried these?

Comment: yes i did try it, the error i get is 'cannot access archive 'powershell_6.0.0-beta.7-1ubuntu1.16.04.1_amd64.deb': No such file or directory'

Comment: it works with this image:  microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0.0-jessie